# How do I create a file in the nix store?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'd like to define/manage a config file within a nix file and have it end up in the nix store, how can I do this?

Currently I'm managing this (outside of the nix store) manually by having the file within a path like `~/example/config.json`, and used like the below:

```
  systemd.services = {
   example = {
      description = "abcxyz";
      serviceConfig = {
        WorkingDirectory = "%h/example/";
        Type      = "simple";
        ExecStart = "${example-pkg}/bin/app -c config.json";
        Restart   = "always";
        RestartSec   = 60;
      };
      wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
    };
```

---

For example Nixos defines a `postgresql` service that has a config file located at `/nix/store/pcp1r7f8mylwvri381an01r64knj1wwb-postgresql.conf/postgresql.conf` - how could I replicate this functionality in my own service above?

Taking a look at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/226ff16bd6fbe6d47e714379eeba8598cd61a90a/nixos/modules/services/databases/postgresql.nix#L21

```
configFile = pkgs.writeTextDir "postgresql.conf" (concatStringsSep "\n" (mapAttrsToList (n: v: "${n} = ${toStr v}") cfg.settings));
```

It's not clear to me what `configFile` is? Will it be the path to the `postgresql.conf` file?

Either way `pkgs.writeTextDir "config.ini"` seems to create a directory instead, should I be using `pkgs.writeText` instead?

Comment: `configFile` is a local variable defined in a [`let` expression](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/language-constructs.html#let-expressions). The file name is given by the argument specified as `"postgresql.conf"`. Local variable names like those introduced by let bindings do not affect anything other than the variable reference expressions in the subexpression after `in`; they can be renamed freely without any side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above seems to work:

```
  configFile = pkgs.writeText "config.json" 
    ''
    example config file bla bla
    '';
```

And then you can use `configFile` via string interpolation:

```
ExecStart = "${example-pkg}/bin/app -c ${configFile}";
```

Comment: There's also `builtins.toFile`, which writes to the store immediately during evaluation, without creating a derivation. Its contents are not allowed to reference derivation outputs, presumably because such a store path would not form a valid closure until the referenced outputs are built successfully.

Comment: I'd recommend `pkgs.write*` over `builtins.toFile` because the `write*` are more general for a marginal cost. Having to change `toFile` calls to `pkgs.writeText` is no fun, especially when it's not in your own code.